# How to teleport a villager with a pseudo NBT tag?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Pseudo NBTs are like NBTs that aren't real like these:

[image]

So I tried doing something like this:

[image][image]

But it says this:

[image]

I don't want mods - I want to do this in vanilla Minecraft.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Arqade!!! I have a segustion, maybe explain your question more by typing it instead of just showing pictures. Because I know that I cannot access the pictures, this would be a great help at helping us solve your problem!!

Answer (score 7):

First of all, those are called "pseudo tags".

Secondly, there is an easy way to accomplish this - tags.

By tags I don't mean NBT tags, but the tags you add on to an entity with the `/tag` command. Simply tag the villager with something and teleport entities of that specific tag.

E.g.
`/tag @e[type=villager,sort=nearest,limit=1] foo`
`/tp @e[tag=foo] to somewhere`

Or

You can summon an entity with a default tag as well

```
/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {Tags:["foo"]}
```

Always look for easier ways to solve a problem.

By the way, I tried out your original command and it seems like your original summon command would *not* summon a villager with the pseudo tag. Even using `/data merge {Fake:1b}` won't do the job. If I were you I would not waste time on this. NBT is simply something that determines entities' properties and there are other, much easier approaches to your problem.